# An analysis problem involving function space and precompactness

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, function-spaces

Let $X$ be a set and $T$ be a compact metric space. $f:X\times X\to T$ is a function.

There are two ways for $f$ to be considered as a function from $X$ to the function space $T^X$ (it is a metric space with $d(f,g)=\sup_i (d(f(i),g(i)))$ ) , that is $f_1(x)= (y \mapsto f(x,y))$ and $f_2(y)= (x \mapsto f(x,y))$.

Prove that the image of $f_1$ is precompact (closure is compact) iff the image of $f_2$ is precompact.